# CloudWatch not receiving Cloudtrail logs from outside region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I am struggling with detecting activities performed outside of a given region in CloudWatch. For example, if an InternetGateway is created in the same region as the CloudWatch Event (let's say eu-central-1), it is detected by CloudWatch, however if it's somewhere else (let's say eu-west-1) it won't catch the event.

However, Cloudtrail does capture the event in the given region (it is activated across regions) as I can see it in the event history of this particular region. (let's say eu-west-1 again).

How can I get CloudWatch to act upon what is happening regardless of the region of creation?

- Should I create the CloudWatch Event in each region, as well as the lambda function associated with the remediation?
- Or is there a way to capture the logs of all regions and deal with them in a singular space?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have a distributed deployment and then collate in one region for one function. Probably should proceed it per region in region. Unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get cross-region cloudtrail logs into a single bucket:

> **Receiving CloudTrail Log Files from Multiple Regions** You can configure CloudTrail to deliver log files from multiple regions to a
>   single S3 bucket for a single account. For example, you have a trail
>   in the US West (Oregon) Region that is configured to deliver log files
>   to a S3 bucket, and a CloudWatch Logs log group. When you apply the
>   trail to all regions, CloudTrail creates a new trail in all other
>   regions. This trail has the original trail configuration. CloudTrail
>   delivers log files to the same S3 bucket and CloudWatch Logs log
>   group.

from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/receive-cloudtrail-log-files-from-multiple-regions.html

Comment: My Trail bucket indeed receives all logs in a singular space. However, the CloudWatch event is not triggered when something happened outside of its region.
Should I create the same CloudWatch event across regions to cover my whole suscription?

Answer (score 1):

I have the a similar problem with CloudTrail going to CloudWatch Logs. I wanted to receive CloudTrail events for both eu-west-1 and global events for Route 53 (which seem to come from us-east-1) into a CloudWatch Logs stream so I could add some further monitoring and alerting of our AWS account.

The documentation for this at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html is quite good and easy to follow, and even mentions:

> **Note**
>
> A trail that applies to all regions sends log files from all regions to the CloudWatch Logs log group that you specify.

However, I could not get this to work. I also tried making the log delivery IAM policy more permissive - the default policy includes the region name in the stream name and I thought this might change for logs from other regions - but this didn't help. Ultimately I could not get anything from outside eu-west-1 to be delivered to CloudWatch Logs, even though events were correctly appearing in the S3 bucket.

I ended up working around this by creating a second duplicate trail in us-east-1 and delivering logs for that region to Cloudwatch Logs also in that region.